# Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in

Tags: hooks

I get an fatal error on the 'add content page'.

Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in

```
function mymodule_form($form, $form_state){
    $form['mymodule'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#description' => t('Please enter your text here.'),
        '#required' => TRUE,
    );
    $form['mymodule_submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => 'Submit this form'
    );

    return $form;
    return node_content_form($node, $form_state);
}
```

The problem's happen when I add my form, when I use only the

```
return node_content_form($node, $form_state);
```

it is working fine, what do I wrong?

Comment: You haven't initialised `$node`

Comment: @GisleHannemyr A couple of lines from the bottom of the question: "The problem's happen when I add my form, when I use only the `return node_content_form($node, $form_state);`. I missed that first too, I think the OP is just switching back and forth between the two returns for testing. `$node` being uninitialised is causing that error when `node_content_form` tries to pass the null object off to `node_type_get_type()`

Comment: @user27485 Please can you clarify what you're trying to  do here? [`hook_form()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_form/7) is used exclusively by modules that declare node types. Is that what you're trying to do, or are you trying to use the form for an existing content type in a different context (maybe at another url, embedded in another page, etc)? Or are you trying to create your own form from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

There are two related but distinct concepts that seem to be conflated in your code, i.e. hook_form, and the notion of a drupal form builder function. [Hook_form](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_form/7) uses the template explained by @gisleHannemyr.

The template for a [form builder function](https://drupal.org/node/1702548) is:

```
function mymodule_example_form($form, &$form_state) {  
  ...
  return $form;
}
```

Use hook_form to create or override node creation forms, and a form builder function for any other (non-node-related) form.

If you simply want to alter an existing (node or other) form, you should use [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7), instead.

Answer (score 1):

It always a good idea to read the [documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_form/7).

The template for `hook_form` is:

```
hook_form($node, &$form_state)
```

The first parameter passed into the (`$node` in the template) is an object.  In your hook, you've called it `$form`.  That is confusing.  You're also treating it as an array.  That is just wrong, and is what triggers the error message you see.

Additional quirks:

The second parameter is passed as reference.  You're implementation is passing it as a value (it won't bite you, since you're not using it, but you better get it right anyway).

You've got a spurious second return statement at the end. It will not do any harm, since it is never executed, but it is confusing.

Here is how your hook should start and end (the bit in the middle looks OK),

```
function mymodule_form($node, &$form_state) {
    $form = array();

    // build the form array.

    return $form;
}
```

Comment: I think there is some confusion here between hook_form and the concept of a builder function for a form. The latter takes $form and &$form_state as args. https://drupal.org/node/1702548

Comment: @olyN, well, the OP's question shows `hook_form` being used.  I that is not what the OP intended to use, he/she needs to edit the question.

Comment: Agreed. So the syntax used in the question mixes the two concepts.

Comment: Great spot @GisleHannemyr, didn't even consider OP might be trying to implement `hook_form()`. Out of both possibilities this makes the most sense with the OP's current code